# $d\lambda$ in the convolution integral vs its counterpart the convolution sum

Tags: integration, summation, convolution

So for a bit of background, in my courses I have been presented to convolution integral and then convolution sum with the following formulas :

Continuous case :
$$x(t)*h(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(\lambda).h(t-\lambda)\ d\lambda  $$
Discontinuous case :

$$x[n]*h[n] = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} x[k].h[n-k] $$

They differ by a "factor" of $\ d\lambda$, loosly speaking.

I put the quotes on the parts where teachers mention that this is "loosly speaking".

After doing convolution in both discrete and continuous modes, I find that $d\lambda$ term to be a noise in the equation as I couldn't see intuitively what was going on. Which led me to question is  $\ d\lambda$ really as it is taught for instance in coordinate systems contexts where it is "a very small piece of $\lambda$".

Am i correct to think of, loosly speaking, of the convolution integral as :

$$x(t)*h(t) = \int_{\lambda = -\infty}^{\infty} x(\lambda).h(t-\lambda)\ $$

Because here it is clear exactly what is going on, as we're not "multiplying by lambda", which is supposed to be a dummy variable to begin with.

And what exactly are these `dλ`, `dt` .. etc ??

In contexts such as describing the integral as the area,

$$Area =  \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx  $$

It makes perfect sense that we would multiply the value of the function with "small pieces of x".

So what am I missing in all this ?

Comment: For the continuous case, we use $d\lambda$, that is:  Lebesgue measure, on $\mathbb R$.  For the discrete case, we use counting measure on $\mathbb Z$.  These are both "Haar measure" for the appropriate group.  In fact, we may define convolution for any locally compact (abelian?) group using Haar measure for that group.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure

Comment: One way to think about it is to realize that these aren't all the same kinds of objects, and one way to see that is to notice that in an applied setting, they don't have the same dimensions.

Comment: (Cont.) For example, in the setting of probability theory, continuous convolution comes up when $x$ and $h$ are probability densities (with dimension of reciprocal length), and then this formula gives you back a probability density again. The $d\lambda$ thus provides the extra factor of length to get you back to reciprocal length units. Discrete convolution comes up in the context where $x$ and $h$ are probability mass functions, which are already dimensionless, and then $x*h$ gives you a probability mass function back, which should be dimensionless again.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for pointing out the units thing, but it's not really what I'm intuitively aspiring to get.

Comment: It's the same explanation even without units; the $d\lambda$ is needed to ensure that the function on the left side is the same "kind of object" as the functions on the right side. These dimensional analysis concepts are baked into the idea of integration, because of change of variables.